# message queue(IPC) receiving process not printing the received data in C

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue

I am implementing message queue mechanism for IPC in C linux. Below is my receiving process. It's not printing the message received. It's generating a valid msqid, and other parameters of msgrcv function are also correct, I think. Why so?

```
//header files
#include"msgbuf.h"
int main()
{
   int msqid;
   key_t key;
   int msgflg = 0666;
   message_buf  *rbuf;
   rbuf=malloc(sizeof(*rbuf));
   rbuf->m=malloc(sizeof(M1));
   key = ftok("/home/user",12);
   if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg)) ==-1)
   {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
   }
   printf("\n\n%d\n",msqid);  //working fine till here.
   /* Receive an answer of message type 1.   */
   if (msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, sizeof(rbuf->m), 1, 0) < 0)
   {
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(1);
   }
   /* Print the answer.  */
   printf("Received message text= %s\n", rbuf->m->cp);
   return 0;
}
```

now msgbuf.h

```
typedef struct msgclient
{
  int msglen;
  int msgtype;
  char *cp;
}M1;


typedef struct msgbuf1
{
   long    mtype;
   M1      *m;
} message_buf;
```

Comment: I have allocated space for cp in server's process. Do I need to allocate space here too??

Comment: No effect of changing even. however *rbuf means space allocated for msglen, msgtype & cp of msgclient and mtype of msgbuf1. So it was not needed though.

Comment: I know this is the general approach. but if my data is not charater array but some structure then how??

Answer (score 1):

Since two separate processes have two separate memory areas it doesn't make sense to pass pointers to another process since the passed pointer, if it points to anything at all in the receiving process, won't be pointing to whatever it was pointing to in the originating process.

You will need to change the `char *cp;` in M1 to a character array and copy the string into it before sending the message buffer.  A length byte indicating the length of string might be advisable (but not necessarily required) as well.

Comment: Thanks @Duck but both processes are on the same machine. so passing pointers should not create problem as well. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Consider yourself corrected.  The only situation where it makes sense is if you are passing ptrs in a queue between threads since all threads will share the same memory because they are in the same process. You can try it your way if you need to convince yourself but isn't that the reason for the question to begin with - that it wasn't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, sizeof(rbuf->m), 1, 0) < 0)
```

Should be

```
if (msgrcv(msqid, &rbuf, sizeof(struct message_buf), 1, 0) < 0)
```

Comment: ** invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct message_buf** This is what I am getting.